# How to render properly

Tags: rendering, lighting, settings

I’m new to Blender and just started 2 days ago. I watched YT and get me started, but I can’t get rendering to work properly. All verticals objects are dark and top surfaces have good. I’m using Light/Sun since I just need my object to be lit. Not fancy but that’s what I need for now.

What am I doing wrong? What setting needs to be changed?

[image]

TIA

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Why? The screenshot shows he is using _Eevee_, the sun points straight down and even _Shadow_ is disabled. And from this premise, L0Lock gave a detailed explanation of what he could do.

Comment: Oh ok my bad I thought he had artefacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Sun light is perfectly pointing down. And I guess you are rendering with Eevee or Workbench since there isn't any visible Global Illumination. So you need to rotate it a bit if you want your walls to receive any lighting.

[image]

> A sun light provides light of constant intensity emitted in a single direction from infinitely far away. It can be very handy for a uniform clear daylight open-space illumination. In the 3D Viewport, the sun light is represented by an encircled black dot with rays emitting from it, plus a dashed line indicating the direction of the light.
>
> Note:
>
> This direction can be changed by rotating the sun light, like any other object, but because the light is emitted from a location considered infinitely far away, the location of a sun light does not affect the rendered result.
>
> Source: [Light Objects — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html#sun-light)

If you use indeed Eevee, you might also want to check a few things:

- Enable contact shadows in your sun light settings:
  [image]
- Enable Ambient Occlusion:
  [image]
- Enable Screenspace Reflections:
  [image]
- Add an object Light Probe > Irradiance volume, make its spheres spread across your scene, and bake Indirect Lighting:
  [image]

Comment: Yes, he uses _Eevee_. The (disabled) _Shadow_ option on the sun lamp is not available in _Cycles_ or _Workbench_. So first of all if he enabled it this would already be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you!!! You are my hero!!!

Comment: @Katsumi Nagata If the answer is correct, mark it as so